# Upstart doesn't recognize desktop-unlock event

Tags: upstart, events

I created an Upstart job under `/etc/init` and it is a simple job as:

```
start on desktop-unlock

exec <my script>
```

My script is under `/usr/bin` and is executable.

But it seems Upstart only recognizes events starting with `:sys:`
I concluded that using upstart-monitor and another job I've made.
This is one screenshot from upstart-monitor:

[image]

I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: I didn't find `desktop-unlock` event in [upstart manual](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/). Did you emit this event with your script?

Comment: You can use `initctl emit -n desktop-unlock` to emit an event to the system instance of Upstart. Is this what you want, or do you need to emit the event as an unpriveleged user?

Comment: Sorry about long absence. My script doesn't emit anything, and i suppose to use the event, not produce it. I've seen many upstart configuration examples using this specific event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Upstart has two types of jobs, session and system. system jobs only react to system events, but session jobs can react to session events or system events (when using the :sys: prefix).

`desktop-lock` and `desktop-unlock` are *session* events. You need to place your upstart job into `~/.config/upstart/` for it to work correctly. Please note that it will therefore be run as your user, not as root.